# The setting 'INSTALL' specified is not recognized. Error code 0x84B40003

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, windows-installer

I am trying to creating a setup project for my Winforms application.  So I followed the instructions in this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLz03-JWWQk

So I attached the SQLEXPRESS installation to the setup file.

Everything went well and the set file was generated, but when I try to install it, I get this error:

> The setting 'INSTALL' specified is not recognized. Error code 0x84B40003

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Righ now i have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove the `Arguments` Value in the property window.For reference find below `screenshot`:

[image]